# How to determine the path & name of the Python shared library?

Tags: python

Given a Python compiled as a shared library, how do I determine the name and path of this library?

The output I'm looking for is like "/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so" or "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python" (for a framework build on OS X).

Comment: I've found the "LDLIBRARY" config variable; set to "libpython2.7.dylib" for a custom-built Python on OS X and "Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python" for the OS X system version (built as a Framework). Unfortunately, neither of these include full path info, and I can't find a suitable var to concat with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how or if it can be done within Python itself, but you can use standard tools for finding shared library dependencies for the python executable.

Linux:  `ldd <path>/python` or `ldd $(which python)`
Mac:    `otool -L <path>/python`
Windows: run [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on python.exe

Answer (score 3):

see https://pypi.org/project/find-libpython/

```
$ pip3 install find_libpython
```

then

```
$ python3 -c 'import find_libpython; print(find_libpython.find_libpython())'
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Python
```

or simply:

```
python3 -m find_libpython
```

Comment: You can now just run `python -m find_libpython`.

Answer (score 3):

With pure Python tested on *Amazon Linux* after a `sudo yum install python3`

```py
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_config_vars('LIBDIR', 'INSTSONAME')  
# -> ['/usr/lib64', 'libpython3.7m.so.1.0']
```

Edit:
Note that some distributions (i.e Linux and Python >= 3.8) will not contain a shared library anymore, but will link statically to libpython3.8.a.

Comment: While it's increasingly less important, it's  worth noting that the `sysconfig` module is only available in Python3.2+.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. In my case, I had to use either `'LIBPL'` or `'srcdir'` to get the directory that contains the shared library.