# CMake could not find Python 3 to build matplotlib-cpp

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cmake, build, windows-10

I am trying to build the matplotlib-cpp library from source on my Windows 10 PC. So here is what I have done:

1. Download the source from the [github repo](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp).
2. Open CMake GUI, and fill in the `Where is the source code` field and the `Where to build the binaries` field with proper paths.
3. Click Configure in CMake GUI. Then I encountered the following error:

   ```
   CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
     Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Development Development.Module
     Development.Embed) (found version "3.9.10")
   Call Stack (most recent call first):
     C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
     C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:2966 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
     C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPython3.cmake:389 (include)
     CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)


   Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
   See also "C:/github/cpp/plt/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
   ```

It seems that CMake is complaining about not finding Python 3. But I double checked using a command line terminal that `python3 --version` returned `Python 3.10.10`. So I wonder why is CMake complaining?

Comment: "I wonder why is CMake complaining?" - CMake complains not about python executable but about python **libraries** which are needed to build C code. You could try code from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64308557/3440745) to check whether you have libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hi, Tsyvarev, thank you for the help. I did try one of the answers in the link, which is `python3 -m find_libpython`, and it did return something: `C:\Users\Tong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll`. But how is this going to help me build the matplotlib-cpp library?

Comment: In the error message CMake notes, that it founds Python 3.9.10, but your description is about Python 3.10.10. In CMake GUI you may inspect value of `Python3_EXECUTABLE` variable. If that value doesn't correspond to your expectations, you could modify it and re-run configuration process.

Answer (score -2):

this is a reason i switched to Linux. windows just sucks for programming. my guess is that it isn't allowed to access the program. i have run into issues before where a program always have to be run with special rights enabled in order to access a certain file or directory. you could try using a virtual machine running linux (i would recommend Ubuntu) or install it on your physical computer (good choice for a programmer) and see if that works. windows has some crap security features that can sometimes prevent certain applications from accessing certain directories on a computer. you could try running CMake as administrator or specifying python's direct path.